# Custom i18n error message gives throws InvalidPluralizationData error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, internationalization

I have a 'user' and a 'profile' model. The user has one to one relationship with profile and 
"accepts_nested_attributes_for profile".

I'm validating profile with two checkboxes - that is to say one of the agreements must be accepted before it's validated.

Anyway, I want to customise the error message for not accepting one of the boxes so I added the following into en.yml

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    user: 
      profile:
        terms_and_conditions_a: 
          accepted: "You must accept the terms and conditions to continue"
        terms_and_conditions_b: 
          accepted: "You must accept the terms and conditions to continue"
```

You'll see that profile is nested under user - this is to stop "Profile" being put at the front of the error message [(as explained here).](http://railsengineer.com/post/3920777973/rails-nested-form-validation-message)

This gives me the error:

```
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData
translation data {:terms_and_conditions_a=>{:invalid=>"You must accept the terms and conditions to continue"}} can not be used with :count => 1
```

I don't really see what it's trying to pluralize, any help?

Comment: Yep I'm using it with a condition eg.  validates_acceptance_of :my_terms_and_conditions, :accept => true, :if => :my_condition

Comment: what is the `association between user & profile`?? Can you put down `form view snippet`?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it should be

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      user: 
        profile:
          attributes:
            terms_and_conditions_a: 
              accepted: "You must accept the terms and conditions to continue"
```

rather than

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    user: 
      profile:
        terms_and_conditions_a: 
          accepted: "You must accept the terms and conditions to continue"
```

?

That's how it is in my app, which is admittedly rails 2 rather than rails 3.

Alternately, try not nesting profile under user:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      profile:
        attributes:
          terms_and_conditions_a: 
            accepted: "You must accept the terms and conditions to continue"
```